# Change Pagination URL in CakePHP v3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm going to upgrade my CakePHP v2 to v3 & wanted to match URL. So I need to change the pagination URL from

```
http://www.website.net/articles
http://www.website.net/articles?page=2
```

to

```
http://www.website.net/articles
http://www.website.net/articles/page/2
```

But seem no working.

This is my Router

```
$routes->connect('/articles', ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index']);
$routes->connect('/articles/page/:page', ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index'], ['pass' => ['page']]);
```

This is my Controller

```
public $paginate = [
    'limit' => 2,
];

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
}

public function index($page = 1)
{
     $this->set('articles', $this->Articles->find('all'));
     $this->set('articles', $this->paginate());
}
```

In CakePHP v2 I have this the below line in Controller which suppose to transfer the page number from router but does not seem to work in v3

`$this->request->params['named']['page'] = $page;`

Appreciate help in this.

Comment: This is a bad idea. You're much better off with query params.

Comment: Why is bad idea?. My site with CakePHP v2 is using this. I want to follow the same convention after upgrading to CakePHP v3.

Comment: http://www.dereuromark.de/?s=query#passed,-named-or-query-string-params?

Comment: OK, I understand the reasoning. Just wondering, we can no longer be able to do this way?? Because I really like to retain the URL structure.